# Django - Permission denied when installing django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

It seems I dont have some permissions to write files on my server which is strange because I'm a user with all the privileges as the "root" has.

I was editing my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, adding my user in `AllowUsers`:

```
AllowUsers myuser
```

Then I've added the privileges on `visudo`

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So, What I'm trying to do is install Django using virtualenv but I'm getting this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/www/some/myvenv/build'
```

after:

```
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
$ pip install Django==1.6.5
```

FYI: I'm installing this stuffs in /opt/www/

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: how did you create myenv?

Comment: Why don't you just change the directory permissions to include your user or one of its groups?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're in the sudoers file, that doesn't give you any more permissions than a regular user. You'll have to run the pip install with the sudo command to run it with admin privileges:

```
sudo pip install Django==1.6.5
```

Of course, you have to be careful when running things with sudo, you might damage stuff etc. etc., so make sure you know what you are doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu then use command

```
sudo pip install Django==1.6.5
```

it will install Django of version 1.6.5

OR

try to give 777 permission on the folder. refer the link : 
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/